# My session object is not getting populated

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I am following a tutorial, this is just a basic login.
I've seen this question a lot but nothing seems to be working on my case, when someone login (there is no database it accepts any user and any password) I create a variable inside my session object, like so: req.session.authenticated, but this variable is undefined in any other route, here is my code:

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const session = require('express-session');
const store = new session.MemoryStore();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use("/", express.static('public'));
app.use(session({
    secret: "123",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store,
    cookie : {
        maxAge: 300000000, 
        secure: false,
        sameSite: 'none'
    }
}));

function checkAuth(res, req, next){
    // here req.session.authenticated is undefined and throws an error
    if(req.session.authenticated){
        return next();
    } else {
        res.json({msg: "no estás logeado"});
    }
}

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
    const {user, password} = req.body;
    res.send("<h1>hola</h1>");
    req.session.authenticated = true;
});

app.get("/profile", checkAuth, (req, res) => {
    // here req.session.authenticated is undefined and throws an error
    res.send("bienvenido");
})

app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log("Server OK!");
})
```

index.html (this is just a basic form) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/login" method="POST">
        <label for="user">Usuario :</label>
        <input type="text" id="user" name="user">
        <label for="pass">Clave :</label>
        <input type="password" id="pass" name="password">
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The error that I am getting:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'authenticated')
    at checkAuth (/home/giovanni/Projects/session-practicas/server.js:22:20)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/giovanni/Projects/session-practicas/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/giovanni/Projects/session-practicas/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/giovanni/Projects/session-practicas/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/giovanni/Projects/session-practicas/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/giovanni/Projects/session-practicas/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (/home/giovanni/Projects/session-practicas/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12)
    at next (/home/giovanni/Projects/session-practicas/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)
    at session (/home/giovanni/Projects/session-practicas/node_modules/express-session/index.js:479:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/giovanni/Projects/session-practicas/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
```